# insert not creating Id?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have created a simple object with getters and setters:

```
public class MemberCanonical : IMemberCanonical
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to insert a new member into the database with:

```
try
{
    memberObj.username = username;
    memberObj.email = email;
    memberObj.status = "active";
    // memberObj.Id = new ObjectId().ToString();
    this.membershipcollection.Insert(memberObj, SafeMode.True);
    return true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return false;   
}
```

I would expect insert to create a unique _id (Id), but that's not happening. Upon insert when I view the _id field I get "0000000...."

What do I need to do in order for Mongo to generate its own _id on insert?

Comment: Sometimes I like to answer questions in subjects I know nothing about. Here's what I found out: You can generate ids yourself using `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()` - You can do it in the constructor of `MemberCanonical`, or check the Id while inserting against `ObjectId.Empty`. Next, it is *possible* it should be called `_id`, I'm not quite sure on that. I'd also try to use `ObjectId?` and set its value to `null`, but that is a wild guess.

Comment: It creates the Id automatically when Id type is ObjectId. which is as expected. If Id is not ObjectId driver will not know how to create that Id and make it unique.So this has to be done manually.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution that doesn't require polluting the domain model with persistence concerns such as a dependency on MongoDB types?

Answer (score 11):

Just mark your Id property with `[BsonId]` attribute, and generated id value will be there!

```
public class MemberCanonical : IMemberCanonical
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

---

```
this.membershipcollection.Insert(memberObj, SafeMode.True);
var idYouLookingFor = memberObj.Id;
```

Or alternative way, suggested by  @Kobi: "use _id field name instead of Id" should also work.

Comment: I just used the [BsonId] attribute on my Id property and I didn't get an automatically generated ID value. My Id property is a string, though. Would you happen to know if it has to be of type ObjectId?

Comment: By the way, the Id property updated when it was of type `ObjectId` and *without* having the `BsonId` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I use a combination of the `[BsonId]` attribute and the constructor to create the Id value.

For example

```cs
public class Something {

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Something() {
        this.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
    }

}
```

This is so that I always have a populated Id field for the object. When the entity is retrieved from the database, the Id field is overwritten with the actual Id value from the database. Win Win.

Answer (score -1):

Use `[BsonId]` on whichever unique property you want to use. You can even ignore the `ObjectID` type and create your own.

For example:

```
[BsonId]
public string studentid{get; set;}
```

Comment: This is identical to an answer from two years ago.